# JQuery Doesn't Update :last Filter for Dynamically Added Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html, input

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm in kind of a bind. I'm creating a JavaScript function to dynamically add form inputs when a user focuses on a particular HTML text input (because we have the option of accepting more than one value). I thought that doing this way would be easier than selecting the amount of inputs you need from a drop-down menu.

Here is how I go about adding the new form inputs:

```
$("input[type=text]").filter(":regex(id, roe[0-9])").filter(":last").on("focus", function() {
    // Add in new elements here
}
```

When I refresh the page, and focus on that initial text input with the ID of "roe0", JQuery generates a new input just how I want it to. However, when I go to focus on the newly generated input, nothing happens. I then have to focus back on the original `$(#roe0)` input to generate a new text input.

Does anyone know of a solution to this? Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thing is that you are selecting one element (The last when the page is loaded), and attaching an event handler to it. Then nothing else is done, so it makes sense that any new elements that you create won't have that event handling.

What I would do is something like this:

```
function createNewElement(e) {
    var newElement = jQuery('<input />');
    // Whatever logic you have to append the new input and such
    newElement.one("focus", createNewElement);
}

$("input[type=text]").filter(":regex(id, roe[0-9])").filter(":last").one("focus", createNewElement);
```

This way, when you create a new element, you're attaching the same event handler to it.

As said in another answer, it would be good to use `one` instead of `on`. It will detach the event handler once it's executed once (Which is good, because the new element should be the one with the event handler now)

Answer (score 2):

It will only be applied once and to the last element at the time of applying. You will need to reapply it to the newly created element. Here would be a good situation to make use of jQuerys `.one()` event binder. As it will essential remove the bind on the element once the event fires for the first time (once).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I didn't know about the `.one()` event previously, but it seems exactly like what I need. Thank you for your answer!